# PRESTASHOP - Criar cascading dropdown category

Tags: dropdown, filtro, filter, e-commerce

Senhores,

Estou tentando e batendo a cabeça para criar um filtro cascading para o Prestashop, baseado em suas categorias, e os plugins que encontrei são pagos.
Qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer?

Se ao menos o Prestashop me retornasse um json, eu conseguiria popular os dropdowns com as categorias, mas acabei ficando sem norte...

essa é minha estrutura:

```
<div id="filtro">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Montadora</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select style="width:100%" name="montadora_tur" required="required" class="form-control" id="montadora_tur">
                                        <option class="montadora_zero" value="">Selecione</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Carro</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select style="width:100%" name="carro_tur" required="required" class="form-control" id="carro_tur">
                                        <option class="carro_zero" value="">Selecione</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Ano</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select style="width:100%" name="ano_tur" required="required" class="form-control" id="ano_tur">
                                        <option value="ano_zero">Selecione</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Alguém teria alguma luz?

Comment: Tem algum código, tem ai o que foi feito, demostre com exemplos o seu problema

Comment: Postei a minha estrutura atual.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic atualizei! Obrigado pela observação!